# Taskbar Issue for My App

Tags: c#, winforms, taskbar

When I click on my Winforms app then its forms are opened in separate section in Taskbar with default C# icon. How can I solve this issue?

[image]

**Update:**

At first I open my login form as bellow:

```
Application.Run(new frmLogin());
```

Then I open my main form from the login form as bellow:

```
this.Hide();
frmMain frmMain = new frmMain();
frmMain.Show();
```

Comment: Share code of `Program.cs` and also show how you open forms. The problem should be reproducible to be solvable. Otherwise the QA will be turned into a guess game.

Comment: @Aidin I had that problem, but i fixed it by restarting `explorer.exe` or Windows Explorer.

Comment: @shad0wk, this is not a solution. Do u have any other idea to solve the problem?

Comment: @Aidin, Did you try restarting it?

Comment: @shad0wk, suppose that the issue solved after restarting; But other users cannot restart windows explorer to solve the issue every time!

Comment: @Aidin Well it's not to do with the program, it's the system, so it's just some annying thing that you have to do. Are you debugging it? If you are, then there's nothing you can do about it, because the program is not your program, it's the debugger vshost

Comment: @shad0wk, no, the issue is about my published version using ClickOnce.

Comment: @Aidin Okay, okay, so then it's the system, there's nothing you can do. Un-pinning and re-pinning programs can cause the problem.

Comment: @shad0wk, I unpinned and re-pinned and the problem solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Aidin Glad it worked. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a system problem. Here are 3 solutions:

1. Restart your computer.
2. Restart `explorer.exe` or File Explorer. [How to do it.](http://lifehacker.com/356915/restart-windows-explorer-the-safe-way)
3. Unpin then re-pin your program on the taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

first solution: you can set this property of the form

[image]

and another solution :

Did you try parent form and child form?

Set Parent of the forms, So they will be open as child of your main form

For Example(In the main form when You want to open another form) :

```
FrmChild frmChild= new FrmChild ();
frmChild.Parent = this;
FrmChild.Show();
```

Comment: If you want to hide it from taskbar set it to false, Sorry i just want to show the property i'll edit it